# Confusing results about the Modern Team Site's Site Owners

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups, modern-team-site

We have a Modern Team site named "TesUserPermision" and i am confused on who is defined as the site owner.

First step >> i went to Site Permission >> i got that the "TestUserPermision Owners" is inside the Site owners, as follow:-

[image]

Second step >> i went to the "Advanced permission setting" >> click on the "TestUserPermision Owners" sharepoint group i found that it is empty:-

[image]

and when i check the user permission i found that any user who is defined as an owner inside the underlying Office 365 group will have full control permission on the sharepoint site... so can anyone advice on my above 2 approaches/steps and why i am getting different results?? and which one i should trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the M365 group Oweners is hidden in the view by default. You could make it show in the view by following the below.

1. Go to Settings-> List settings:
   [image]

2.Click Detail View in the views:

[image]

3.Remove the filter:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply.. finally i understand what is going on... but any idea why this is hidden by default? second question, is there any harm if we remove the "Test Owners" from the Test Owner sharepoint group?

Comment: I think this could be that the M365 group and SharePoint group have the same name, it would make users confused. So Microsoft make the M365 group (group members and group owners) hidden in the view. Besides, we cannot remove the M365 group "Test Owners" from the Test Owner sharepoint group. The check box is disabled in the view for M365 group "Test Owners".

Answer (score 0):

M365 Group Owners are Site Collection Administrators, hence full control.

Comment: but in our case the site collection admin contain my username only and does not contain M365 Group Owners ....

Comment: Have you removed the M365 group owners from Site Collection Administrators group? I don't know for certain but it's quite likely that it will synchronise M365 owners and they may be put back in to the Site Collection Administrators group. This is part of the M365 group connected aspect of SharePoint Online.

Comment: @CallumCrowley yes the site collection admin group only contain my user name ...seems that :-Any users who have Owner role inside Office 365 group will have full permission on the sharepoint site even if this user is not explicitly defined as site admin or site owner inside the sharepoint site..

Comment: @CallumCrowley also as mentioned in my question there is a confusion and conflict on who is define as the site owner,, i think this is a bug and need to be fixed!! as we get 2 different results depend on from where we are viewing the site owners

Comment: If you feel there is a bug, you can raise a ticket with Microsoft via the Microsoft 365 admin portal.